# Implementing Mahalanobis Distance from scratch in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, distance

I am implementing Mahalanobis Distance from scratch but an error occurred.
The formula of Mahalanobis Distance is- 
[image]
I am providing my code below with error-

```
from math import*
from decimal import Decimal
import numpy as np

def mahalanobis(x, y, cov=None):
    x_mean = np.mean(x)
    y_mean = np.mean(y)
    y_minus_mn = y - y_mean
    x_minus_mn_with_transpose =np.transpose(x- x_mean)
    Covariance = covar(x, y)
    inv_covmat = np.linalg.inv(Covariance)
    x_minus_mn = x - x_mean
    D_square = np.dot( x_minus_mn_with_transpose, inv_covmat, x_minus_mn)
    return D_square

def covar(x, y):
    x_mean = np.mean(x)
    y_mean = np.mean(y)
    Cov_numerator = sum(((a - x_mean)*(b - y_mean)) for a, b in zip(x, y))
    Cov_denomerator = len(x) - 1
    Covariance = (Cov_numerator / Cov_denomerator)
    return  Covariance

import pandas as pd

filepath = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/selva86/datasets/master/diamonds.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(filepath).iloc[:, [0,4,6]]
df.head()

X = df[['carat', 'depth', 'price']].head(500).values.tolist
Y =df[['carat', 'depth', 'price']].values.tolist

mahalanobis(X, Y)
```

Error - below picture
[image]

Plz help. Is there anyone who can check and correct my code

Comment: Please see why [pictures of exceptions are not helpful](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/).

Answer (score 2):

```
X = df[['carat', 'depth', 'price']].head(500).values.tolist
Y =df[['carat', 'depth', 'price']].values.tolist
```

> .tolist

It's function. I think you need:

> .tolist()

Comment: Note if you use type hints, [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/) could have caught this error for you. i.e. `def mahalanobis(x: np.array, y: np.array, cov: np.array = None) -> np.array:`. Mypy would have given you an error that made a lot more sense.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of errors in your code that i shall point out

1. Use np.cov for computing covariance when you are working with numpy arrays, don't reimplement everything
2. The third argument to np.dot is the output, so instead of `D_square = np.dot( x_minus_mn_with_transpose, inv_covmat, x_minus_mn)` you should write `D_square = np.dot(np.dot(x_minus_mn, inv_covmat), np.transpose(x_minus_mn))`
3. instead of `X = df[['carat', 'depth', 'price']].head(500).values.tolist`
   use `X = np.asarray(df[['carat', 'depth', 'price']].head(500).values)`. if your'e using numpy then work with numpy arrays only, not lists.

here is a modified version of the code you provided

```
import numpy as np

def mahalanobis(x, y, cov=None):
    x_mean = np.mean(x)
    Covariance = np.cov(np.transpose(y))
    inv_covmat = np.linalg.inv(Covariance)
    x_minus_mn = x - x_mean
    D_square = np.dot(np.dot(x_minus_mn, inv_covmat), np.transpose(x_minus_mn))
    return D_square

import pandas as pd

filepath = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/selva86/datasets/master/diamonds.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(filepath).iloc[:, [0,4,6]]
df.head()

X = np.asarray(df[['carat', 'depth', 'price']].head(500).values)
Y =np.asarray(df[['carat', 'depth', 'price']].values)

mahalanobis(X, Y)
```

Comment: why did you use np.transpose(y)

Comment: Thanks for the help but I also want to implement the covariance from scratch

Comment: because we are computing the covariance with respect to our features, so the covariance matrix should be of shape 3x3 where 3 is the number of features here. y is of shape (num_inputs, num_features) so passing this will give you a covariance matrix of shape (num_inputs, num_inputs), while what we want is a covariance matrix of shape (num_features, num_features)

Comment: you can implement computing the covariance matrix from scratch just make sure that you're returning a numpy array in your Covariance function and not list.

Comment: Can you help me with that